# My View's onClick is triggering anywhere on the whole layout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a row of buttons and adding it to a RelativeLayout.
All seems well except that the button's onClickListener is triggering if I touch any portion of the screen.

I would like to ask two questions:

First, How come it is listening to the whole layout instead of just the view.

Second, is there a better way to implement what I'm doing? I'm creating a grid of buttons which I think is nasty. I'm quite new to Java and I am not quite familiar with any similar class that might be similar to what I am doing.

here's snippet of my code:

```
    final RelativeLayout idStageFrame = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.idStageFrame); //set to wrap_content
    stageNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Place the button in a Grid Position
            int placeX = 0;
            int placeY = 0;
            for (ctr = 0; ctr <= stageTotal - 1; ctr++ ){
                stage[ctr] = new stageButtons(StageActivity.this, ctr + 1);
                stage[ctr].putOnThisLocation(placeX, placeY);

                stage[ctr].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent startPlay = new Intent(StageActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
                        startActivity(startPlay); // It calls the next activity if I touched anywhere on screen.
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                idStageFrame.addView(stage[ctr]);
                placeX++;
                int z = (ctr + 1) % 4;
                if ( z== 0) {
                    placeY++;
                    placeX = 0;
                }

            }
```

stage class is:

```
public class stageButtons extends View implements View.OnClickListener{
public int stageTag;
Context appBase;
Paint paint;
int butW;
int butH;
int putH;
int putW;
float charW;

public stageButtons(Context base, int tag){
    super(base);
    stageTag = tag;
    appBase = base;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(60);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        paint.setAlpha(255)
        c.drawBitmap(generateBitMap(stagePreview), putW, putH, paint);
        c.drawText(String.valueOf(stageTag), putW + (butW / 2) - (charW / 2), putH + (butH / 2) + (30), paint);
    }
}


public void putOnThisLocation(int x, int y){

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)appBase.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);
    int screenWidth = display.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = display.heightPixels;

    putW = x * (screenWidth / 4) + 5;
    putH = y * (screenHeight / 4) + 5;
    butH = (screenHeight / 4) - 10;
    butW = (screenWidth / 4) - 10;
    charW = paint.measureText(String.valueOf(stageTag));

}

private Bitmap generateBitMap(String bitMapName){
    // generate Bitmap from Asset Folder
    // required path to bitmap

    Bitmap alienBitMap = null;
    try{
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        InputStream bgStream = appBase.getAssets().open(bitMapName);
        alienBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bgStream, null, opt);
        alienBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(alienBitMap,butW, butH , true);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return alienBitMap;
}

}
```

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: hi,stage is another class that implements View. I basically add it there since I want to make a custom image with a numbers on it. I'm adding the code on the post

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your requirement.
But if you want to open another screen when click on other places instead of specific place then you need to use proper click-listener or touch-listener instead of above looping concept.

Comment: well, I want to call another screen my View is clicked. I created the loop in order to add several buttons which is quite repetitive.